# Splitting a list recursively in Scheme

Tags: scheme, racket

What I want to do is define a list such as (define lst '(1 2 3 4 5 6)) and then call (split lst) which will return '((1 3 5) (2 4 6)).

Some examples:

- When `lst` is `'(1 2 3 4 5 6)` it should return `'((1 3 5) (2 4 6))`
- When `lst` is `'(1 2 3 4 5 6 7)` it should return `'((1 3 5 7) (2 4 6))`
- When `lst` is `'("a" "little" "bit" "of" "that" "to" "spice" "things" "up")` it should return `'(("a" "bit" "that" "spice" "up") ("little" "of" "to" "things"))`

It should alternate when building the two lists. So the first index should go in the first list, second index in the second list, third index in the first list, etc.

Here is my current script.

```
(define (split lst)
  (cond ((null? lst) lst)
        ((null? (cdr lst)) lst)
        ((cons (cons (car lst) (split (cddr lst))) (cons (cadr lst) (split (cddr lst)))))))
```

Currently, this is what outputs when I split the list '(1 2 3 4 5 6)

```
((1 (3 (5) 6) 4 (5) 6) 2 (3 (5) 6) 4 (5) 6)
```

Comment: what should `(split lst)` return when `lst` is `(1 2 3 4 5 6 7)` ?

Comment: it should return '((1 3 5 7) (2 4 6))

Comment: Does that mean it should return the odd numbers, and then the even numbers? Or something else?

Comment: I figured how the algorithm would work is it would alternate when building the two lists. so the first index would go in the first list, seocnd index in the second list, third index in the first list, etc.

Comment: So on `(list "a" "little" "bit" "of" "that" "to" "spice" "things" "up")` should it return `(list  (list "a" "bit" "that" "spice" "up")  (list "little" "of" "to" "things"))` ?

Comment: Correct, that is the plan.

Answer (score 5):

Lets fix your code step by step:

```
(define (split lst)
  (cond ((null? lst) lst)
        ((null? (cdr lst)) lst)
        ((cons (cons (car lst) (split (cddr lst))) (cons (cadr lst) (split (cddr lst)))))))
```

The first thing I notice is the lack of an `else` in the last case of the `cond`. Conds are supposed to look like:

```
(cond (question-1 answer-1)
      (question-2 answer-2)
      ...
      (else else-answer))
```

With an `else` inserted your code looks like this:

```
(define (split lst)
  (cond ((null? lst) lst)
        ((null? (cdr lst)) lst)
        (else
         (cons (cons (car lst) (split (cddr lst))) (cons (cadr lst) (split (cddr lst)))))))
```

The next thing is the first base case, or the answer to the `(null? lst)` cond question. On an empty list what should it return?

It seems like no matter how long the list is, it should always return a list of exactly two inner lists. So when `lst` is empty the logical answer would be `(list '() '())`.

```
(define (split lst)
  (cond ((null? lst) 
         (list '() '()))
        ((null? (cdr lst)) lst)
        (else
         (cons (cons (car lst) (split (cddr lst))) (cons (cadr lst) (split (cddr lst)))))))
```

Next is the second base case, the answer to the `(null? (cdr lst))` cond question. Again it should return a list of exactly two inner lists:

```
(list ??? ???)
```

The the first index should go in the first list, and then there's nothing to go in the second list.

```
(list (list (car lst)) '())
```

In the context of your code:

```
(define (split lst)
  (cond ((null? lst)
         (list '() '()))
        ((null? (cdr lst))
         (list (list (car lst)) '()))
        (else
         (cons (cons (car lst) (split (cddr lst))) (cons (cadr lst) (split (cddr lst)))))))
```

Now, what is the behavior of this function?

```
 > (split '(1 2 3 4 5 6))
 '((1 (3 (5 () ()) 6 () ()) 4 (5 () ()) 6 () ()) 2 (3 (5 () ()) 6 () ()) 4 (5 () ()) 6 () ())
```

Still not what you want. So what is the last case, recursive case, supposed to do?

Consider what you're "given" and what you need to "produce".

Given:

- `(car lst)` the first element
- `(cadr lst)` the second element
- `(split (cddr lst))` a list of exactly two inner lists

You should produce:

- `(list ??? ???)`

Where the first `???` hole contains the first element and the first of the two inner lists, and the second `???` hole contains the second element and the second of the two inner lists.

This suggests code like this:

```
(list (cons (car lst)  (first (split (cddr lst))))
      (cons (cadr lst) (second (split (cddr lst)))))
```

Or, since `car` gets the first and `cadr` gets the second:

```
(list (cons (car lst)  (car (split (cddr lst))))
      (cons (cadr lst) (cadr (split (cddr lst)))))
```

In the context of your code:

```
(define (split lst)
  (cond ((null? lst)
         (list '() '()))
        ((null? (cdr lst))
         (list (list (car lst)) '()))
        (else
         (list (cons (car lst)  (car (split (cddr lst))))
               (cons (cadr lst) (cadr (split (cddr lst))))))))
```

Using it produces what you want:

```
> (split '(1 2 3 4 5 6))
'((1 3 5) (2 4 6))
> (split '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7))
'((1 3 5 7) (2 4 6))
> (split '("a" "little" "bit" "of" "that" "to" "spice" "things" "up"))
'(("a" "bit" "that" "spice" "up") ("little" "of" "to" "things"))
```

Now what was the difference between this and what you had before?

Your code before:

```
(cons (cons (car lst)  (split (cddr lst)))
      (cons (cadr lst) (split (cddr lst))))
```

The fixed version:

```
(list (cons (car lst)  (car (split (cddr lst))))
      (cons (cadr lst) (cadr (split (cddr lst)))))
```

The first difference is that your original version uses `cons` on the outside, while the fixed version uses `list` instead. This is because `(list  ???  ???)` always returns a list of exactly two elements, while `(cons  ???  ???)` can return a list of any size greater than 1, which has the first thing merged onto an existing second list. `(list ??? ???)` is what you want here because you specified that it should return a list of exactly two inner lists.

The second difference is in how you use the recursive call `(split (cddr lst))`.

This has to do with how you interpreted the "given" part of the recursive case. You had assumed that the first call to `split` would give you the first "inner" list, and the second call to `split` would give you the second "inner" list. In fact it gives you a list of *both* of those both times. So for the first one you have to get the "first" or `car` of it, and for the second one you have get the "second" or `cadr` of it.

Comment: Alright, I understand your thinking on this, as it's pretty similar to what I was trying to do myself. At the end of your script. You're using 'first' and 'second' which are not defined anywhere within the function. Why?

Comment: Oh, in the implementation of Scheme I use, `first` is an alias to `car`, and `second` is an alias to `cadr`. I use them because they're more descriptive and they just make the code easier to read. But I can change them.

Comment: Oh no it's fine. I was just reading over it. Appreciate the walkthrough and explanation!

Comment: in the implementation of Scheme *I* use, `first` is an alias to `car`, and `second` is an alias to `cadr`, but I always use `car` and `cadr` (and `cddr`), because  they are unambiguous, short, have rich history behind them, and just make the code that much easier to read -- *for me.* :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this might be what you're looking for:

```
(define (split lst)
  (define (loop lst do-odd odds evens)
    (if (null? lst)
    (list (reverse odds) (reverse evens))
    (loop (cdr lst) (not do-odd)
          (if do-odd (cons (car lst) odds) odds)
          (if (not do-odd) (cons (car lst) evens) evens))))
  (loop lst #t '() '()))
```

In use:

```
1 ]=> (split '(1 2 3 4 5 6))

;Value 2: ((1 3 5) (2 4 6))

1 ]=> (split '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7))

;Value 3: ((1 3 5 7) (2 4 6))
```

This uses the variable `do-odd` in the inner loop function (which is tail-recursive, by the way, so it is fast!) to figure out which list it should add the `(car lst)` to.

Downsides to this function: the call to `reverse` in the base case can be expensive if your lists are very long. This may or may not be a problem. Profiling your code will tell you if it's a bottleneck.

**UPDATE**: You can also use the function `reverse!`, which destructively modifies the array in question. I did some informal profiling, and it didn't seem to make that much of a difference speed-wise. You will have to test this under your specific circumstances.

Now, if this isn't intended to be performant, use whatever you want! :)

Answer (score 0):

**My shortest solution**

```
(define (split l)
  (cond ((null? l) '(() ()))
        ((null? (cdr l)) (list (list (car l)) '()))
        (else (map cons (list (car l) (cadr l))
                        (split (cddr l))))))
```

**Similar but wordier solution**

Ensure that `split` always returns a list of two lists.
Then you can define it quite compactly:

```
(define (split l)
  (cond ((null? l) '(() ()))
        ((null? (cdr l)) (list (list (car l)) '()))
        (else (double-cons (list (car l) (cadr l))
                           (split (cddr l))))))
```

with `double-cons` being:

```
(define (double-cons l lol)
  (list (cons (car l) (car lol)) 
        (cons (cadr l) (cadr lol))))
```

**`double-cons`**:

```
(double-cons '(a 1) '((b c) (2 3)))
; => '((a b c) (1 2 3))
```

**Other `double-cons` definitions**

This takes more lines but makes it easier to read:

```
(define (double-cons l lol)
  (let ((e1 (car l))
        (e2 (cadr l))
        (l1 (car lol))
        (l2 (cadr lol)))
    (list (cons e1 l1) (cons e2 l2))))
```

Or a double-cons which `cons`es even more elements and lists in parallel:

```
(define (parallel-cons l lol)
   (map cons l lol))
; it is `variadic` and conses as many elements with their lists
; as you want:
(parallel-cons '(1 a A '(a)) '((2 3) (b c d e) (B C) ((b) (c))))
; '((1 2 3) (a b c d e) (A B C) ('(a) (b) (c)))
; this combination of `map` and `cons` is used in the shortest solution above.
```